# Android onClick and startActivity not woking

Tags: android, onclick, floating-action-button, start-activity

```
 ImageView iconStartWorkout = new ImageView(this);
    iconStartWorkout.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_fitness_center_black_24dp);

    ImageView iconNewWorkout = new ImageView(this);

    iconNewWorkout.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_format_list_numbered_black_24dp);
    iconNewWorkout.setClickable(true);
    iconNewWorkout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            startActivity(new Intent(this,AddDate.class));
        }
    });
```

iconStartWorkout  is part of `FloatingActionMenu`. Android studio underlines and said `cannot resolve constructor'Intend [...]'`

but class `AddBase` has all needed stuff:

```
public class AddDate extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_date);
}}
```

I used `startActivity( new Intent(this, sth.class));` and it was working in other projects..

EDIT 1 part of xml

```
<android.widget.ImageView
    android:id="@+id/NewWorkout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_format_list_numbered_black_24dp"/>
```

and

I change in mainActivity

```
 ImageView iconNewWorkout = new ImageView(R.id.NewWorkout);
//iconNewWorkout.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_format_list_numbered_black_24dp);
```

but underline `R.id.NewWorkout` and said `in ImageView cannot be applied to (int)`

Comment: post if any error?

Comment: In your onClick() you should pass like startActivity(new Intent(YourActivityName.this,AddDate.class));

Comment: try to add  android:clickable="true" in ur xml

Comment: still the same error

Comment: Your class name AddBase or AddDate ?

Comment: Try Log.i("Image" , "Clicked"); on your onClick()

Comment: name is AddDate and still the same error

Comment: @Xalion : I updated my answer please take a look

Answer (score 1):

Try like this,

```
iconNewWorkout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this , AddDate.class);
        startActivity(i);

       //OR
       //startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,AddDate.class));
     }
  });
```

and also check your manifest.xml

```
<activity
        android:name=".AddDate"/>
```

This may helps you.

EDIT 1:

Try to give

```
ImageView iconNewWorkout = new ImageView(R.id.YOUR_IMAGEVIEW_ID);
```

instead of

```
ImageView iconNewWorkout = new ImageView(this);
```

Comment: I have the same now (manifest.xml too), there is not error now, but onClick doesnt work.

Comment: xml of AddDate? it is too big now(a lot of text fields).I used; New->Activity-> empty activity, so i thnikt xml should be ok.

Comment: try my EDIT answer

Answer (score 1):

You must pass `Context` or `Activity` to your `Intent`. When you use `this` inside an `oncliclListener` it means you pass `onClickListener` to the `Intent` which is not correct. if you are in activity use this:

```
new Intent(YOURACTIVITY.this,AddDate.class);
```

and if you are in fragment you can use this:

```
new Intent(getApplicationContext(),AddDate.class);
```

Edit:
The second part of your problem is about defining your `ImageView` 
you must find your view using `findViewById()` method like this:

```
 ImageView iconNewWorkout =(ImageView) findViewById((R.id.NewWorkout);
```

Comment: there is no error now, but button does not work.  (my Activity is 'MainActivity')

Answer (score 1):

> cannot resolve constructor'Intend [...]

I assume problem for your `this` .Simply you should pass your Current Activity Name there .

Android **Explicit intent** specifies the component to be invoked from activity.
You can use this way ,

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Your_Current_class_Name, AddDate.class);
 startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: @Milad I have no problem if user comment why down voted . I have no problem . In here for enhance my knowledge .

Comment: @Milad indeed indeed .

Comment: yes its correct answer. inside onClick we should not use this keyword. because in onClick this is not refering to current Activity.

Comment: @HammadTariqSahi roger that .